# Stop Camera recording and save file when entering background

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I've been looking for the answer for 2 days, but I can't seem to get it right...

I have an example app that records audio and video from the device using a AVCaptureSession and a AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.

When I start recording I call:

```
[self.movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

And it starts recording to the file. If I press the button again it stops recording

```
[self.movieFileOutput stopRecording];
```

Everything works well, but when I enter background (incoming call or HOME press) I get an error in the delegate method: didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL

My desired action should be saving / completing the file on entering the background. If I call stopRecording on "applicationDidEnterBackground" it will enter background before the applicationDidEnterBackground is called. On entering the active state it is called.... and generates an error and leaves a corrupted movie file...

It seems that it hasn't got enough time to save the file.

What am I missing here?

This is my Error

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11818 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo=0x17594e20 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions using the recording device and try again., NSUnderlyingError=0x175d3500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16133.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped}`

```
AVErrorSessionWasInterrupted = -11818
```

Comment: I've also tried the Apple AVDemo app and it also gives the same Error. It seems that the error is thrown anyway. The difference is that in Apples' code they have time to execute extensive code using UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSOperationQueue` is the recommended way to perform multi-threaded tasks to avoid blocking the main thread. Background thread is used for tasks that you want to perform while your application is inactive, like GPS indications or Audio streaming.

If your application is running in foreground, you don't need background thread at all.

For simple tasks, you can add a operation to a queue using a block:

```
NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Perform long-running tasks without blocking main thread
}];
```

More info about [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [how to use it](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/).

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

      // Wait until the pending operations finish
      [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

      [application endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go for me. I did implement this piece of code from Apples' example code but I made a stupid mistake... the filename extension changed each time the movie got saved and therefor looked corrupted -1 for me......

Answer (score 1):

You can handle saving in `applicationWillResignActive:` and then you can continue your process in background.

Comment: That's not working, somehow I have to make sure the session doesn't get interrupted when going into background.

Comment: then you have to make another thread.. and you have to handle that thread when its entering in background..

Comment: Check, the applicationWillResignActive doesn't give me enough time for processing. In Melih Büyükbayram it does!

Comment: @Michiel I was trying to say the same thing. I dint see his answer.